# how can i validate image using Joi-browser in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, joi

in the backend there is no issue i can upload the photo using POSTMAN but i cant upload from the client(react ) side its says 'image must be string'

**// node backend schema validation**

```
const Joi = require("joi-browser");
Joi.image = require("joi-image-extension");

const image = new mongoose.Schema({
image: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  })

// validation function
function validateEmployee(employee) {
  const schema = {
   image: Joi.image().required(),   
  };
```

**FRONT-END REACT code ...**

```
import Joi from 'joi-browser'
    
     schema = {
        _id: Joi.string(),
        fullName: Joi.string().required().label('Full Name'),
        email: Joi.string().required().label('Email'),
        phoneNumber: Joi.number().required().label('Phone Number'),
        branchId: Joi.string().required().label('Branch'),
        jobId: Joi.string().required().label('Job'),
        salary: Joi.number().required().label('Salary'),
        image: Joi.string().required().label('image'),
      }
```

Comment: You have set image to Joi.string() so of course it expects a string.

Comment: i just set the image to joi.string() cuz i dont know any specific validation function to validate the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured out on my own joi.any() did the trick and it worked !

Comment: Great , can you mark question as answered.

Comment: yeah i tried to mark it but the site is saying i can mark it as answered afer 22 hours idk the reason

Comment: ah ok.. that's fine.. didn't know about it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what worked for you ? would be helpful for people searching for the same.

Answer (score 0):

set the object name as key & Joi.any() will set as value.

Steep 1:

```
<HQForm className="p-4 border rounded-sm w-100" onSubmit={onSubmit} schema={fileTitle}>
    <HQInput
    name="title"
    label="Title"
    required
    />
    <HQInput
    type="file"
    name="files"
    label="Upload"
    />
</HQForm>
```

Steep 2:

```
import Joi from "joi";

const fileTitle = Joi.object({
  title: Joi.string()
    .required()
    .messages({ "string.empty": "Enter a file title." }),
 files: Joi.any()
});

export default fileTitle;
```